# ActionBarActivity: cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, android-actionbaractivity

I am new to android-programming. I am following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html) tutorial to add an **ActionBar** to my Main_Activity using the explanation in the "**Support Android 2.1 and Above**" section.

I followed [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) tutorial to add a Library-Project. Then after adding the library, at the point "*Add the library to your application project*: I felt lost .. basically because I don't have the "*add*" option by itself in my Eclipse ..

however I clicked on "*add library*" and moved on ..

now when I change `Activity` to `ActionBarActivity` :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { ... }
```

in my mainActivity.java , it gives me error (a red line bellow the ActionBarActivity and  all methods' names and some functions) .. and again when i change:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
```

in the Manifest, it also give me an error saying:  *No resource found that matches the given name* ..

I am totally lost .. what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does not sound like you imported the library right especially  when you say `at the point Add the library to your application project: I felt lost .. basically because I don't have the "add" option by itself .. however I clicked on "add library" and moved on ..`

in eclipse you need to **right click on the project**, go to **Properties**, select **Android** in the list then **Add** to add the library

follow this tutorial in the docs

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: I followed the same tutorial .. but when I open _Properties_, it always opens at _Java build Path_ and then when i go to _Libraries_ I found no add .. yours is more clear and **it is working now** .. **thanks**

Comment: Note that as the "support library" is now deprecated it is not lised by default - there is only the "support repository". You need to check the "show: obsolete" checkbox to see it.

Answer (score 30):

Check if you have a `android-support-v4.jar` file in YOUR project's lib folder, it should be removed!

In the tutorial, when you have followed the instructions of `Adding libraries WITHOUT resources` before doing the coorect `Adding libraries WITH resources` you'll get the same error.

(Don't know why someone would do something like that *lookingawayfrommyself* ^^)

So what did fix it in my case, was removing the `android-support-v4.jar` from YOUR PROJECT (not the android-support-v7-appcompat project), since this caused some kind of **library collision** (maybe because in the meantime there was a new version of the suport library).

Just another case, when this error might shows up.

Comment: Strangely this solves it. Good thing am moving to android studio.

Comment: Note that this error also comes up for me if I have "closed all projects" before creating a new android project. In particular, the appcompat_v7 project must be open, as well as my new project, in order to build the new project.

Comment: removing the android-support-v4.jar saved my life. Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 20):

This way work for me with Eclipse in Android developer tool from Google
 -righ click - property - java build path - add external JAR

point to: android-support-v7-appcompat.jar in /sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs

Then

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also following the instructions on http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/setting-up.html

and even though I did everything in the tutorial, as soon as "extends Action" is changed to "extends ActionBarActivity" all sorts of errors appear in Eclipse, including the "ActionBarActivitycannot be resolved to a type"

None of the above solutions worked for me, but what did work is adding this line to the top:

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of copy/pasting** the code from the tutorial, use the code suggestion in the IDE. Start typing "extends ActionBar..." it will propose "ActionBarActivity" click enter. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**:

Since the version 22.1.0, the class **ActionBarActivity** is deprecated, so instead use **AppCompatActivity**.
For more details [see here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

**Using ActionBarActivity**:

> **In Eclipse**:

1 - Make sure library project(appcompat_v7) is open & is proper referenced (added as library) in your application project.

2 - Delete android-support-v4.jar from your project's libs folder(if jar is present).

3 - Appcompat_v7 must have android-support-v4.jar &  android-support-v7-appcompat.jar inside it's libs folder.
   (If jars are not present copy them from /sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs folder of your installed
     android sdk location)

4- Check whether ActionBarActivity is properly imported.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

> **In Android Studio**

Just add compile dependencies to app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

[Reference](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com.tr/2013/07/how-to-add-actionbarcompat-to-your.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but things got complicated when I added few other libraries like appcompat.v7, recyclerView, CardView.

Removing appcompat.v4 from lib did not work for me.

I had to create project from start and first step I did is to remove appcompat.v4 from libs folder, and this worked.

I had just started the project so creating a new project wasn't a big issue for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your 'andrroid-sdk' folder.
You selected some features while creating new project which need some components to import.
It is needed to download a special android library and place it in `android-sdk` folder.
For me it works fine: 
1-Create a folder with name `extras` in your `android-sdk` folder
2-Create a folder with name `android` in `extras`
3-[Download](http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/extras/support.zip)  this file.(In my case I need this library)
4-Unzip it and copy the content (support folder) in the current `android` folder
5-close `Eclipse` and start it again
6-create your project again

I hope it to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse, modify `project.properties` like this: (your path please)

```
android.library.reference.1=../../../../workspace/appcompat_v7_22
```

And remove `android-support-v4.jar` file in your project's `libs` folder.