# ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type how to resolve

Tags: android

Hi can some one help me on this error. In my project I have `ABS` and `appcompactv7_3` added as libraries. I've got following errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 43 Java Problem  
ActionBarActivity cannot be resolved to a type  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 58 Java Problem  
...
/SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 20 Java Problem  
Cache cannot be resolved to a type  FB_Fragment.java
...
Entry cannot be resolved to a type  FB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 65 Java Problem
Entry cannot be resolved to a type  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 96 Java Problem
Entry cannot be resolved to a type  GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 78 Java Problem
ImageCache cannot be resolved to a type LruBitmapCache.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 9  Java Problem
ImageContainer cannot be resolved to a type FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 55 Java Problem
ImageContainer cannot be resolved to a type FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 132    Java Problem
...
/SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 236    Java Problem
ImageListener cannot be resolved to a type  FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 157    Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    AppController.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 19 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    AppController.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 42 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    AppController.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 44 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    AppController.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 46 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    AppController.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 46 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    AppController.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 49 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 50 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 85 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 87 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 157    Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 26 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 57 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 58 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 104    Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 108    Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 24 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 55 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 56 Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 102    Java Problem
ImageLoader cannot be resolved to a type    FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 106    Java Problem
JsonObjectRequest cannot be resolved to a type  FB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 81 Java Problem
JsonObjectRequest cannot be resolved to a type  FB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 81 Java Problem
JsonObjectRequest cannot be resolved to a type  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 112    Java Problem
JsonObjectRequest cannot be resolved to a type  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 112    Java Problem
JsonObjectRequest cannot be resolved to a type  GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 94 Java Problem
JsonObjectRequest cannot be resolved to a type  GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 94 Java Problem
Method cannot be resolved to a variable Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 112    Java Problem
NetworkImageView cannot be resolved to a type   FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 66 Java Problem
NetworkImageView cannot be resolved to a type   FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 66 Java Problem
NetworkImageView cannot be resolved to a type   FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 64 Java Problem
NetworkImageView cannot be resolved to a type   FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 64 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomAdapter.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 38 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomAdapter.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 40 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomAdapter.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 41 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomAdapter2.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 58 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomAdapter2.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 60 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomAdapter2.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 61 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CustomAdapter2.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 62 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 44 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 46 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 55 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 60 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 62 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 64 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 65 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 67 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 69 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 53 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 58 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 60 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 62 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 63 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 65 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 67 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 59 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 69 Java Problem
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new Thread(){}   MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 33 Java Problem  
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Loging.AttemptLogin  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 138    Java Problem  
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Loging   Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 88 Java Problem  
The method onPause() of type Loging must override or implement a supertype method   Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 164    Java Problem  
The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method   MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 125    Java Problem  
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 117    Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type User_prfile must override or implement a supertype method   User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 19 Java Problem  
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type Post_activity must override or implement a supertype method Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 18 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 23 Java Problem  
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method  MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 18 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type Loging must override or implement a supertype method    Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 58 Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type Infro_frind must override or implement a supertype method   Infro_frind.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 20 Java Problem
The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (Loging, String, int) Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 158    Java Problem  
The method invalidateOptionsMenu() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle(){}  Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 91 Java Problem  
The method invalidateOptionsMenu() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle(){}  Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 97 Java Problem
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity   MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 28 Java Problem
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Home   Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 134    Java Problem
The method setTitle(CharSequence) of type Home must override or implement a supertype method    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 148    Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type User_prfile User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 32 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type Home must override or implement a supertype method Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 154    Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type User_prfile User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 24 Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Post_activity   Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 32 Java Problem
The method onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem) of type Home must override or implement a supertype method   Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 160    Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Post_activity   Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 24 Java Problem  
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Loging  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 64 Java Problem  
The method onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu) of type Home must override or implement a supertype method    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 178    Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Infro_frind Infro_frind.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 35 Java Problem  
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Infro_frind Infro_frind.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 25 Java Problem  
The method onPostCreate(Bundle) of type Home must override or implement a supertype method  Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 191    Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Home    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 57 Java Problem
The method onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) of type Home must override or implement a supertype method Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 198    Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Home    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 56 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type MainActivity MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 120    Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type Home Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 155    Java Problem
The method getIntent() is undefined for the type Infro_frind    Infro_frind.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 29 Java Problem
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type Home   Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 72 Java Problem
The method getTitle() is undefined for the type Home    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 54 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type User_prfile User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 23 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type User_prfile User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 22 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Post_activity   Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 23 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Post_activity   Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 22 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle(){}   Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 95 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type new ActionBarDrawerToggle(){}   Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 89 Java Problem
The method getRequestQueue() from the type AppController refers to the missing type RequestQueue    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 77 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Loging  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 63 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Loging  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 62 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Infro_frind Infro_frind.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 24 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Infro_frind Infro_frind.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 23 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Home    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 150    Java Problem
VolleyError cannot be resolved to a type    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 106    Java Problem
VolleyLog cannot be resolved    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 107    Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Home    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 79 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Home    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 78 Java Problem
The method finish() is undefined for the type new Thread(){}    MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 40 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    LruBitmapCache.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 6  Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 13 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 14 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 15 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 16 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 12 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 11 Java Problem
The method getRequestQueue() from the type AppController refers to the missing type RequestQueue    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 95 Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 10 Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 3  Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 3  Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 2  Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 5  Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 15 Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    Infro_frind.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 3  Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 18 Java Problem
The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Frind_ptofile    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 145    Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 14 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 15 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 16 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 17 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 18 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 19 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 20 Java Problem
The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved    Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 25 Java Problem
The constructor ProgressDialog(Loging) is undefined Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 105    Java Problem
The method onCreate(Bundle) of type Frind_ptofile must override or implement a supertype method Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 57 Java Problem
The constructor Intent(Loging, Class<Register>) is undefined    Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 87 Java Problem
The constructor Intent(Loging, Class<Home>) is undefined    Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 136    Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Frind_ptofile   Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 61 Java Problem
The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type Frind_ptofile   Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 62 Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Frind_ptofile   Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 63 Java Problem
The constructor Intent(Frind_ptofile, Class<Infro_frind>) is undefined  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 143    Java Problem
The method getIntent() is undefined for the type Frind_ptofile  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 70 Java Problem
Response cannot be resolved to a type   GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 103    Java Problem
The method getResources() is undefined for the type Frind_ptofile   Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 75 Java Problem
Response cannot be resolved to a type   GP_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 94 Java Problem
Response cannot be resolved to a type   Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 122    Java Problem
The constructor FeedListAdapter(Frind_ptofile, List<FeedItem>) is undefined Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 85 Java Problem
Response cannot be resolved to a type   Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 113    Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 17 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 18 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 32 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 31 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 27 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  User_prfile.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 21 Java Problem
The method getImageLoader() from the type AppController refers to the missing type ImageLoader  FeedListAdapter2.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 56 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  TB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 40 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  TB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 39 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  TB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 38 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  TB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 36 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  TB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 35 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  TB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 33 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 54 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 52 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 51 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 50 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 49 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 48 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 47 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 46 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Register.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 44 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 32 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 31 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 27 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 6  Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 7  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Post_activity.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 20 Java Problem
The method getImageLoader() from the type AppController refers to the missing type ImageLoader  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 26 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 147    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 130    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 120    Java Problem
The method getImageLoader() from the type AppController refers to the missing type ImageLoader  FeedListAdapter.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 58 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 29 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/example/sn  line 25 Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 4  Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 5  Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 6  Java Problem
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 7  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  MainActivity.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 20 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 86 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 83 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 71 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 70 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 69 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 68 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 67 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Loging.java /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 60 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Infro_frind.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 35 Java Problem
...
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 181    Java Problem
VolleyError cannot be resolved to a type    FeedImageView.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 158    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Home.java   /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 167    Java Problem
...
Response cannot be resolved to a type   FB_Fragment.java    /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 81 Java Problem
...
R cannot be resolved to a variable  Frind_ptofile.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 75 Java Problem/SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 69 Java Problem
RequestQueue cannot be resolved to a type   AppController.java  /SN/src/com/FINAL/sn    line 70 Java Problem
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your imports.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActionBarActivity: cannot be resolved to a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830736/actionbaractivity-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Comment: what is the issue with my import could pls explain

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the support library to you Module. Your `build.gradle` end with:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
}
```